# Python: How to convert items in MySQLCursor.execute() iterable to std::string?

Tags: python, types

I'm new to Python and I find the lack of strongly typed variables very confusing. (I'm very much used to C, Java, VB, etc.)

I'm developing an addon for Kodi.

```
class MyAddon(pyxbmct.AddonDialogWindow):

    def somefunc(self):

        #this is a GUI scrollable list
        self.list = pyxbmct.List()

        query = ("SELECT category FROM test")
        #initialize _connection variable
        self.mysql_connect() 
        cursor = self._connection.cursor()
        for category in cursor.execute(query, multi=True):
            self.list.addItem(category)
```

And I get the following error:

```
self.list.addItem(category)

TypeError: Failed to convert to input type to either a std::string or a p.XBMCAddon::xbmcgui::ListItem
```

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) does not specify the return data type of the items in the iterable returned by MySQLCusor.execute() method. (How can a method return an object of specific type when methods don't even have a return type in Python, I wonder)

The pyxbmct.List.addItem method takes a string or a listItem object as the parameter, which is clearly specified in the [API documentation](http://romanvm.github.io/Kodistubs/_autosummary/xbmcgui.html#xbmcgui.ControlList)

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

P.S.: The str object does not work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `pyxbmct.List.addItem()` takes a string, and assuming that the `category` field in your database is text (char, varchar, etc.), then you should be able to take the first element of the tuple returned by query (bound to the variable `category`) and pass that to `addItem()`:

```
    for category in cursor.execute(query, multi=True):
        self.list.addItem(category[0])
```

If you print out the value of `category` you will see that it is a tuple.